# Specific user clicking ads track in analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, mixpanel, appsflyer

I have 2 ads from Google and Facebook to install my app

The user clicks the ad and signups on my app
Is there a way to track on my analytics which specific ad led him to install my app (fb or google)?

**P.S.** Not asking for the click count on the ad. Example scenarios:

**SCENARIO1:** user1 clicks FB ad and installs my app but did not register.

**SCENARIO2:** user2 clicks google ad, installs my app and register (track this)

Comment: Any reason you tagged this question with AppsFlyer?  The AppsFlyer does it automatically so you can see it in AppsFlyer  dashboard

Comment: Yes but all I can see is the click counts :( The client wants the idea of: 1. mixpanel (people feature) PLUS 2.we should know which ad they have clicked to install the app (should be connected to the registered user after signing up).... I have read many analytics but cant find any analytics that supports this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read many analytics but cant find any analytics that supports this

Please read [AppsFlyer User Acquisition Attribution](https://www.appsflyer.com/product/mobile-attribution/):

> User Acquisition Attribution
>
> Attribute every app install to the marketing campaign and media source
>   that drove it. Granular dashboards report which network or channel, **ad
>   type**, ad group, and ad creative drove each user.

AppsFlyer will tell you from which media source the user installed your app.

[image]

> SCENARIO1: user1 clicks FB ad and installs my app but did not register.
>
> SCENARIO2: user2 clicks google ad, installs my app and register (track this)

Through [AppsFlyer SDK](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032066-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-iOS) you will be able to track *register* event  and filter those events in dashboard

---